# image won't show up online

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to get an image to appear online, although it appears locally.

The funny part is that there are several similar images right next to it that show up, but this particular one will not.

Here's the html:

```
 <p class="home"><a href="index.html"></a></p>
```

And the accompanying CSS:

```
.home {
position:absolute;
left:350px;
top:40px;
display:block;
width:125px;
height:50px;
text-indent:-9999px;
}
.home a {
display:block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:transparent url(home.png) no-repeat top left;
outline:none;
}
.home a:hover {
background-position:0 -50px;
}
```

Comment: Well, you do need quotes around the:    
background:transparent url('home.png') no-repeat top left;    
like that.

not sure if that's what you are asking for or not.

Comment: @BlueMeanie though technically correct, most browser will have no problem with this.. plus it works locally

Comment: @nick-d Have you tried re-uploading the image? maybe it got corrupted during upload. What happens if you try to open the image directly in the browser?

Comment: @BlueMeanie, this worked like a charm.  Although the other pictures didn't need it for some reason...

Comment: @BlueMeanie Quotes around the url property are [not required](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the case, but we'll just remove the possibilities. It somewhat happened to me the same way before.

The image may be in the wrong format or corrupt. Try to re-save the PNG you want from Photoshop, save as Web, or try to save as JPG (or other than PNG). Upload the image and make sure it is in the same directory where the **index.html** is (basing from your code).

Second is, try setting a specific height and width to `.home a`

If none works, put your code over here http://jsfiddle.net/ and check that the path of the image is pointed accordingly.